# EmailSendDefinition EmailSubject vs DynamicEmailSubject

Tags: email, marketing-cloud, api

I am trying to duplicate an EmailSendDefinition via API and ran into an issue where the EmailSubject is being truncated when retrieved via API.

I did some testing and noticed that the DynamicEmailSubject was not truncated and contained the entire contents of the subject and it didn't matter if the subject was static or dynamic.

Therefor my fix is to set the new EmailSendDefinition.EmailSubject to the DynamicEmailSubject of the retrieved ESD.

My question, **is my fix going to land me in any trouble down the road?**

**Will the DynamicEmailSubject always contain the entire subject provided by the user?**

My tests make it appear so, however I would like some validation from someone who is more familiar with the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is the purpose of the DynamicEmailSubject field.  EmailSendDefinition.EmailSubject was available in the SOAP API prior to DynamicEmailSubject so in order to not cause a problem for any integrations where EmailSubject was expected to max out at 200 characters, the longer subject is returned in the new field.